# iOS 6 - Resume animation after come back to app from background

Tags: ios, animation, ios6, multitasking

I have an app that starts spinning a UIImageView when a download begins.  The animation works fine until I go into the background and I can't seem to restart the animation.  I am using UINotificationCenter and I have subscribed to both UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification and UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification.  I have tried using [Technical Q&A QA1673](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1673/_index.html) but those don't seem to do anything.  My background and foreground notification methods look like:

```
    - (void)didEnterBackground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
//    NSArray *animationKeys = [_downloadSpinnerImageView.layer animationKeys];
//    animationWithPosition = [[_downloadSpinnerImageView.layer animationForKey:@"transform"] copy];
//    [self pauseLayer:_downloadSpinnerImageView.layer];

    [_downloadSpinnerImageView.layer removeAllAnimations];
}

- (void)willEnterForeground:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
//
//    if(animationWithPosition != nil)
//    {
//        [_downloadSpinnerImageView.layer addAnimation:animationWithPosition forKey:@"transform"];
//        animationWithPosition = nil;
//    }
//    
//    [self resumeLayer:_downloadSpinnerImageView.layer];
//    [self refreshDownloadStatusView];

    [self refreshDownloadStatusView];
}
```

I am starting the animation using:

```
CABasicAnimation *fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
fullRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];
fullRotation.duration = 10;
fullRotation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
fullRotation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
[_downloadSpinnerImageView.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"360"];
```

Sorry if this seems like a duplicate but everything else I have found had to do with resuming the animation from the last position and not starting it over.  I can't even get it to start over.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint on willEnterForeground or done any other logging to determine if it's even being called?

Comment: @jsd Yeah I did and both didEnterBackground and willEnterForeground are being called.